# USB virtual storage device service

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, software

I'm not sure if this exists.

I have a client with a DVR that will accept a USB drive as a backup location. On an ubuntu server, can I create an empty file with dd, attach it to whatever the service is called, connect both computers with a usb cable (ignore cable length for now), and present that to the DVR from the server as a virtual storage device that can be formatted and used as a backup location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for [Linux USB Gadget mass storage](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/mass-storage.txt)

[Here](https://linux-sunxi.org/USB_Gadget/Mass_storage) is a tutorial.

Nevertheless, your Linux host must support USB OTG mode of operation, which isn't very frequent on server hardware.

Comment: This sounds like what I need. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 3):

There’re was a project called Aclouda and it could do a similar thing but with ARM CPU and internal flash & disk. I don’t know how functional it’s and what it costs.

http://aclouda.com/

This is similar Linux project, but it’s development stalled.

https://github.com/ueno/libusb-gadget